# How to set up OSB service in eclipse?

Tags: osb

I did some research on this. Everywhere I have seen that, this is coming as package.

Weblogic/Eclipse IDE/OSB.

How can I use the Eclipse as client and connect to OSB server, deploy to server for testing.

i don't want to install any services.

Also I have installed Jdeveloper, that is not supporting OSB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Eclipse distribution you need to use is OEPE (Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse).

[There is a guide on how to get a development environment set up on the Oracle Middleware blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/middleware/entry/installing_eclipse_for_osb_development).

Do make sure you get compatible versions, though, even minor version differences can be a problem:

> To ensure the Eclipse version is compatible with your OSB version I recommend using the Eclipse that comes with the supported WLS server, e.g. OSB 11.1.1.4 you would install WLS 10.3.4+oepe.

I'm not sure exactly what you mean when you say "I don't want to install any services".

If you mean you don't want to install OSB as a windows service, then don't. You will be able to start and stop the server with the startWeblogic.cmd file after installation.

If you mean you don't want to install OSB separately, then you won't be able to deploy to anything. OEPE just provides tools to work with OSB or Weblogic, it doesn't have a server as part of the software. If you are concerned about installing OSB, all of the configuration is stored in the "Oracle Home" directory, which you will specify yourself.

Comment: Can I work the Eclipse as client and I can connect to the OSB server ? Like Install OEPE in my local and connect to OSB from other server ?

Comment: You absolutely can, yes, if you look at the blog link I posted, scroll to step 22. That's the start of the section on how to add a remote server. All you need is the server IP or hostname, port and user credentials.

Comment: I installed only `OEPE`, OSB plugin is not there

Comment: The top two comments in the blog have the answer. There was the same question, and the blog author responded saying: [I used the WebLogic Server OEPE, not the straight OEPE install. To get the right downloads go to the following link:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/indexes/downloads/index.html

depending on your OSB version you will need to download the right software..."](https://blogs.oracle.com/middleware/entry/installing_eclipse_for_osb_development#comment-1313350154372)

Comment: the blog was moved

Comment: I'm speculating, but I expect the blog was moved because it is no longer relevant. It is very old, but can be found at the Internet Archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20131211102543/https://blogs.oracle.com/middleware/entry/installing_eclipse_for_osb_development