# OSB Configuration jar

Tags: eclipse, jar, oracle11g, weblogic11g

New to the create Oracle service Bus configuration development. My problem is i couldn't find option called Oracle service Bus configuration in the eclipse when i try to import/export or create new Oracle service Bus Configuration development. Can anybody help me with this please.

I have downloaded oepe 10.3.6 with the oracle web logic server and oracle coherence.

All am concerned is using this option, i have to import sbconfig.jar file to eclipse. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set up OSB service in eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011029/how-to-set-up-osb-service-in-eclipse)

Answer (score -1):

We can only import OSB projects. We cannot import OSB configurations.
So first create an OSB configuration project in OEPE after that import your jar file.

The Configuration project is just like a container which holds all your OSB projects.